# Is it possible to make the compiler see VC name (from string) as that VC type?

Tags: swift

I'm trying the make a function that receives a name (String) of a View Controller and then presents that View Controller modally. Example:

```
func presentViewControllerModally(newViewControllerName: String){

     let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(newViewControllerName)_Identifier") as! newViewControllerName
     self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

But I can't make the `as! newViewControllerName` to work as if the `newViewControllerName` is the type of the `newViewControllerName` and not the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to get the real viewController type in return, just use generics to do this.

```
func presentViewControllerModally<T: UIViewController>(newViewControllerName: String) -> T? {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(newViewControllerName)_Identifier") as? T {
        self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        return newViewController
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then call

```
let myVC: MyVController = presentViewControllerModally(newViewControllerName: "MyVC")
```

**If you don't need the right type but just UIViewController, you don't need a cast**.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t have to downcast controller to your custom subclass. You can just present `UIViewController`.